# Java spark using expr from column value

Tags: java, apache-spark, hadoop, bigdata

I am working on a dataset whose format is as follows:

```
+-------+----------------------------------------------------------------+--------------+
|id     |expression                                                      |gender        |
+-------+----------------------------------------------------------------+--------------+
|1      |CASE WHEN gender ='1' THEN true ELSE false  END                 |1             |
|2      |CASE WHEN gender ='1' THEN true ELSE false END                  |1             |
|3      |CASE WHEN gender ='1' THEN true ELSE false END                  |2             |
|4      |CASE WHEN gender ='1' AND date<> null THEN true ELSE false END  |2             |
 ...     
+-------+----------------------------------------------------------------+--------------+
```

I want to apply SQL rules stored in columns of this same dataset, to check conditions and create a column and get the following dataset:

```
+-------+----------------------------------------------------------------+--------------+---------+
|id     |expression                                                      |gender        |isValid  |
+-------+----------------------------------------------------------------+--------------+---------+
|1      |CASE WHEN gender ='1' THEN true ELSE false END                  |1             |true     |
|2      |CASE WHEN gender ='1' THEN true ELSE false END                  |1             |true     |
|3      |CASE WHEN gender ='1' THEN true ELSE false END                  |2             |false    |
|4      |CASE WHEN gender ='1' AND date<> null THEN true ELSE false END  |2             |false    |
 ...                                            
+-------+----------------------------------------------------------------+--------------+---------+
```

I am currently using Java spark and I was planning to use the following code:

```
myDataset = myDataset.withColumn("isValid", functions.expr("CASE WHEN gender ='1' THEN true ELSE false END");
```

However, the withColumn function only accepts strings and I don't know how to get the contents of the "expression" column.
So this code does not work

```
myDataset = myDataset.withColumn("isValid", functions.expr(myDataset.col("expression");
```

In addition, the checks in the expression column do not always check the same conditions (it can be a check in one or more columns of the dataset, with equals, different, more than ....).
After much research, I don't find anythings for solve this problem.
Do you have any idea ?
Thank you.